# Although the two characters are the same, the condition behaves as if they are not the same in java

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am trying to count each character in strings. My function getting two strings.

when I debugging my code I saw a very strange thing for me.
Although the two characters are the same, the condition behaves as if they are not the same. my expectation is when they are the same to increase the value of lcounbir.You can see the below

```
public class ContainStr {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(containString("hostr1ell","ehllo"));



    }

    public  static boolean containString(String str1,String str2){

        int str2lenght=str2.length();
        int str1lenght=str1.length();

        int[] str1ar=new int[str2lenght];
        String [] strbirar=new String[str1lenght];
        String [] strikiar=new String[str2lenght];
//        int vl=1;
//        int zerocounter=0;


        for(int i=0 ;i<str1lenght;i++){

            strbirar[i]=String.valueOf(str1.charAt(i));


        }
        for(int i=0 ;i<str2lenght;i++){

            strikiar[i]=String.valueOf(str2.charAt(i));


        }
        int lcounbir=0;
        int lcouniki=0;
        int contson=1;

        for (String letter:strikiar
             ) {
            for(int i=0;i<str2lenght;i++){

                if(letter==strikiar[i]){
                    lcouniki+=1;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<str1lenght;i++){
                if(letter==strbirar[i]){
                    lcounbir+=1;
                }
            }
            if(lcounbir!=lcouniki){
                contson=0;
                break;

            }
        }
        if (contson==0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use `.equals` to compare Strings. Alternatively, keep the characters as primitive `char`s and you can compare them using `==`.

Comment: Their value is same and not the reference . What you are doing here is reference comparison and not value comparison , Use .equals instead as @hev1 mentioned

Comment: Thank you so much.it's working perfectly.